# Plot dates on x-axis when data is obtained through index

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I use the dates as x-axis while keeping the granularity of using the indices as data points?

**The data looks like this:**

[image]

This is how the plot should look like. However, the date are off. I obtain these result by using `data.index` or `data.date.index`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(data.date.index, data.Euro, label='EUR')
```

[image]

I get this plot using `data.date`. The plot is not showing all data points, however the dates are correct:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(data.date, data.Euro, label='EUR')
```

[image]

What is the easiest way to keep the date representation but to also display all data points properly?

Comment: what is data.date? What's its type? and what is data?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(data.date, format='%y')` - pass that into the function.

Comment: My bad, added head of the data.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Awesome, `ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(data.date, format='%Y%m%d'), data.Euro, label='EUR')` solved it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by coldspeed, following worked for me:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(data.date, format='%Y%m%d'), data.Euro, label='EUR')

plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('1 USD in EURO', fontsize=14)
ax.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

Another solution is to set an index column and parse the column when loaded:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y%m%d')
data = pd.read_csv('../input/cd07244106ca8b3f.csv',
                   parse_dates=['date'],
                   index_col='date',
                   date_parser=dateparse)
```

and then
 later just use:

```
ax.plot(data.index, data.Euro, label='EUR')
```

[image]